# Shell commands with a pipe in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a shell command from python but as soon as I add a pipe, I get a "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. I tried a variety of things and even referenced grep directly at /bin/grep. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Works:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Doesn't Work:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls | grep '20'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Displayed Error:

```
[OMITTED]$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ls | grep '20'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[OMITTED]$
```

Version:
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe `|` **is a shell feature**. If you want to use it, you have to use Popen with `shell=True`.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls | grep '20'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

**NOTE:**

> Warning Passing shell=True can be a security hazard **if combined with
>   untrusted input**. See the warning under Frequently Used Arguments for
>   details.

Source: [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @paullb you are welcome !)